# Parsing String in Java, then storing in variables

Tags: java, arrays, string, parsing

I need help to parse a string in Java... I'm very new to Java and am not sure how to go about it.

Suppose the string I want to parse is...

String str = "NC43-EB2;49.21716;-122.667252;49.216757;-122.666235;"

**What I would want to do is:**

String name = C43

String direction = EB2;

**Then what I'd like to do is store 2 coordinates as a pair...**

Coordinate c1 = 49.21716;-122.667252;
Coordinate c2 = 49.216757;-122.666235;

**And then make a List to store c1 and c2.**

So far I have this:

> parseOnePattern(String str) {
>
> String toParse = str;
>
> ```
>     name = toParse.substring(1, toParse.indexOf("-"));
>     direction = toParse.substring(toParse.indexOf("-", toParse.indexOf(";")));
> ```

I'm not sure how to move forward. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Depending on the consistency of your data, you might want to look into Regular Expressions. What does this problem have to do with JSON? Your strings are not in JSON format, otherwise you'd use the JSON Parser API: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html

Comment: Sorry nothing to do with JSON, I have edited my answer.... If I would like to develop a regex to store each coordinate as a pair, how would I go about doing that? I notice that every second coordinate begins with a "-", perhaps that could be of some help.


I thought to separate each coordinate I would use 
String[] result = s.split(";");

Comment: It looks like you've got some decent answers below with splitting, if they solve your issue, then you're good (make sure to mark them as solved). If you're interested in starting the regex pattern and experimenting before you implement it, checkout https://regex101.com/. I love that site. If you need a Java regex tutorial, you can find plenty through Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple substring function may solve your problem.

> ```
>    String str = "NC43-EB2;49.21716;-122.667252;49.216757;-122.666235;";
>    String[]s = str.split(";");
>    String[]n = s[0].split("-");
>   
>    String name = n[0].substring(1);       
>    String direction = n[1]; 
>           
>    String c1 = s[1] +";"+s[2];        
>    String c2 = s[3] +";"+s[4];
>
>    System.out.println(name + " " + direction);
>    System.out.println(c1 + " " + c2);
> ```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str3 = "NC43-EB2;49.21716;-122.667252;49.216757;-122.666235;";
String sub = str3.substring(0,4); // sub = NC43
String sub4 = str3.substring(5,9); // sub = EB2;

HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
hm.put(str3.substring(9 ,30), str3.substring(30));

hm.forEach((lat, lot) -> {
    System.out.println(lat + " - " + lot); // 49.21716;-122.667252; - 49.216757;-122.666235;
});

//edit if using an array non pairs (I assumed it was lat + lon)
List<String> coordList = new ArrayList<>();
coordList.add(str3.substring(9 ,30));
coordList.add(str3.substring(30));

coordList.forEach( coord -> {
    System.out.println(coord);
});

//output : 49.21716;-122.667252;
           49.216757;-122.666235;
```

Comment: I will have more data for coordinates than just the given 4 values, so I don't think this will be good to implement this for a mass amount of data bcuz you are specifying specific values for the substring method... what do you think?

Comment: It depends whether your Strings have the same length. I assumed they would. The amount of data is no problem since you can write your own method, that would do the splitting. Then loop over it for each String.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Java and the whole set of operations it allows to perform on Strings. You have a whole set of operations to perform, I will give you the code to perform some of them and get you started :-

```
public void breakString() {
    String str = "NC43-EB2;49.21716;-122.667252;49.216757;-122.666235";
    // Will break str to "NC43-EB2" and "49.21716" "-122.667252" "49.216757" "-122.666235"
    String [] allValues = str.split(";", -1);
    String [] nameValuePair = allValues[0].split("-");
    // substring selects only the specified portion of string 
    String name = nameValuePair[0].substring(1, 4);

    // Since "49.21716" is of type String, we may need it to parse it to data type double if we want to do operations like numeric operations
    double c1 = 0d;
    try {
    c1 = Double.parseDouble(allValues[1]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // TODO: Take corrective measures or simply log the error
    }
```

What I would suggest you is to go through the documentation of String class, learn more about operations like String splitting and converting one data type to another and use an IDE like Eclipse which has very helpful features. Also I haven't tested the code above, so use it as a reference and not as a template.

Comment: Thank-you this is very helpful... but what does the -1 parameter mean in the split method (I know it's the limit but how was this determined?) Also, I'm not sure where in the code you have specified how to parse the coordinates... (and yes you are right, I would have to parse each string coordinate to double).

Comment: Here is a direct quote from documentation - The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. f n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

Comment: As for the coordinates, there is no in built Coordinates class in Java. There is one obscure class called Points but I don't think  you want that. You would have to create your own custom Coordinates class with, perhaps, lat/long as member variables and store these double values in them. Try looking for Classes in Java

Answer (score 0):

Ok i made this:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "NC43-EB2;49.21716;-122.667252;49.216757;-122.666235;";

    String[] strSplit = str.split(";");
    String[] nameSplit=strSplit[0].split("-");
    String name=nameSplit[0].replace("N", "");
    String direction= nameSplit[1];
    String cordanateOne = strSplit[1]+";"+strSplit[2]+";";
    String cordanateTwo = strSplit[3]+";"+strSplit[4]+";";

        System.out.println("Name: "+name);
        System.out.println("Direction: "+direction);
        System.out.println("Cordenate One: "+cordanateOne);
        System.out.println("Cordenate Two: "+cordanateTwo);

}


Name: C43
```

Direction: EB2
Cordenate One: 49.21716;-122.667252;
Cordenate Two: 49.216757;-122.666235;